# Composer - Installation keeps on failing

Tags: php, windows, codeigniter, composer-php

I am having a problem in installing Composer. Would you help me solve this?

Here is my scenario:

Before, I am using Composer. I can install packages in my project with no problems. My life was easy. But all of a sudden, something went wrong and I don't what it is. I do not change any configuration in my computer. If I do composer update, there is an error.

something like: 
zlib_decode() data error.

I cannot post the screenshot of the error because I already uninstalled Composer hoping that If I reinstall it the problem would be solved.

So I have uninstalled composer, and tried to reinstall it. But now I cannot install Composer using both the windows cmd, and the composer-setup.exe. In the windows cmd, It says, "Installer is corrupted", In the composer-setup.exe the message is : (Failed to decode zlib stream)

Here is what I have tried so far:

- I have disabled ESET antivirus. and IPV6 (composer.org degraded mode)
- I have disable the firewall.
- I have uninstalled composer. but now I cannot install it again.

Here are the other details hope it would help:

- I am using Windows 10 64bit
- I am using CodeIgniter
- I am using XAMPP for Windows
- I am running PHP 7.1
- I don't know if it is relevant but we have a company domain. and maybe firewall

If there is anything you need to know I will provide it. Hope you can help me with this. Hope I explained my self well. Thanks!

Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot in bash]

[Screenshot when installed using windows cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLMpR.png)

Comment: can you share screenshot of the error you getting in the answer @danangeloakcanar

Comment: Hi @saurabhkamble, I have attached the screenshot. Please see above. Thanks!

Comment: is composer command working @danangeloalcarnar

Comment: @saurabhkamble, Yes it is working, It's strange but I am able to install it again. if I run composer,  it shows the composer text and the list of options. But if I run composer update, still the same error.

Comment: link from where did you install the composer and Environment Variables added can check once

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/download/ that is the link. I have tried both the exe installer and also installing using windows cmd. Thanks!

Comment: path: C:\Users\dralcanar\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin. PATH: C:\Users\dralcanar\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

Comment: why are you trying in bash can you reinstall and configure it on prompt

Comment: I already tried that @saurabhkamble. But I tried it again. I will attached above the screenshot of the result.

Comment: Hi @saurabhkamble, the problem is in the network I am connected to. I can use Composer at home without any problem. Thanks! :)